# WooCommerce: I want to update the label on the checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, label, checkout

As my title, I just want to update the content on the checkout page. Such as fist name, last name, company name, address..... I want to edit these labels in into others. Such as change company name. Where can I find it? I tried the database, files and php pages, but nothing relatived there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather to change the code, i will suggest you to use plugin "Woo Checkout Field Editor Pro". It offers you to add/remove checkout fields, rename labels etc. Its free. See this link :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/

See, i changed the email label.

[image]